# Is cucumber suitable for non-web project?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, bdd

I want to develop a network system. It is not based on rails and has no html UI.

Do I have to do BDD in this case? Does using Cucumber make sense?

Comment: "I" is capitalized, and sentences start with capital letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used Cucumber plenty for non-Rails applications. It's useful for testing full use cases, regardless of the interface. For example, testing multiple runs of a command-line application quickly.

Comment: Does cucumber support TCP request ? Could you please give me one demo, i want to know how to do this. thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure about TCP requests, but probably. If you want an example of that I can't give it to you, but if you want an example of using Cucumber with a command-line app check out http://github.com/jferris/trout

Comment: @rspeicher I want to ask: how to run your project without building gem ? that's to say how to run and run the feature in your source code? just run : ruby ./bin/trout.rb ?

Comment: If you just run `cucumber` from the root directory it should run everything in the features folder.

Comment: Your feature is pretty good. but i am not clear with "And I run "git init", Does cucumber can recognise these shell command ?

Comment: Given a directory named "upstream_repo"--how cucumber to do with this 
? I', confused with this.

Comment: Those kinds of steps are from an awesome gem called Aruba - http://github.com/aslakhellesoy/aruba